# Finding the Default version in a large linage tree

Tags: arcgis-10.0, enterprise-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase, versioning

I have a very large versioning linage tree. I am using the arcGIS 10.0 [GDBT](http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/geodatabase/details?entryID=C05E5891-1422-2418-7F0B-4EDDADA28872) tool. How can I find the node with the default version?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wish that `Versioning Lineage` had a Find option.

The best workaround that I have found is to

1. Export to TSV (Tom Sawyer Visualization), which is an XML File. 
   [image]
2. Open in Notepad++, or your favorite text editor(the TSV is an XML file).
3. Search for your version name (e.g. dbo.DEFAULT, SDE.DEFAULT).
4. Look at the `<Center>` tag for the x,y of the node. And use that to figure out where in your chart your version is (0,0 is lower left).

   ```
   <node id="345">
     <center x="1781.0" y="17672.0"/>
     <nodeLabels>
       <nodeLabel id="346">
         <name value="dbo.DEFAULT"/>
         <size height="14.0" width="67.0"/>
       </nodeLabel>
     </nodeLabels>
     <tooltip value="dbo.DEFAULT"/>
     <graphics type="shapeNode">
       <fillColor value="255 0 0"/>
     </graphics>
   </node>
   ```

Optionally, you could actually change the x,y values and open the file back up again in the GDBT Version Lineage window.  I'll usually do an X=0 and a Y= to slam the DEFAULT node to the upper left.  And then you can follow it's connector down its State node.  And now you'll have an idea of where your version will be back in the original chart:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I usually print to PDF using CutePDF Writer and then I can search the tree using acrobat reader search command (CTRL + F).